# Round down datetime to previous hour

Tags: python, datetime, rounding

How to round down datetime to previous hour? for example:

```
print datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
>> 2017-01-11 13:26:12.0
```

round down to previous hour: `2017-01-11 12:00:00.0`

Comment: If your date is `2017-01-11 00:11:22`, do you want your date to be on the previous day? Do you need to consider Daylight Saving Time?

Comment: no, I want it to be `2017-01-11 00:00:00`

Comment: @DougKruger: I'm a bit confused: you say you want to round down to the *previous* hour, but in your comment, you seem to only round down. Is this only the case at the beginning of a day? Or do I overlook something?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Given you want to **round down to the hour**, you can simply replace `microsecond`, `second` and `minute` with zeros:

```
print(datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0, second=0, minute=0))
```

---

If you want to round down to the **previous** hour (as stated in the example `2017-01-11 13:26:12.0` to `2017-01-11 12:00:00.0`), replace `microsecond`, `second` and `minute` with zeros, then subtract one hour:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

print(datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0, second=0, minute=0) - timedelta(hours=1))
```

Example in the shell:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> print(datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0, second=0, minute=0) - timedelta(hours=1))
2017-01-11 16:00:00
```

Answer (score 12):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

n = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
new_date = datetime(year=n.year, month=n.month, day=n.day, hour=n.hour)
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

currTime = datetime.now()

floored = pd.to_datetime(currTime).floor('H').to_pydatetime()
```

Comment: to use `pandas` to round datetime is like shooting flies with space shuttles