# Make Seconds and Minutes equal to 00 in datetime list python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, datetime, python-datetime

I have a python list of dates in the format of `2014-07-06 11:03:12` is there a way to change the seconds and minutes to `2014-07-06 11:00:00` in a nice way. My line of code for getting the dates in below

```
dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime (d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in df.date] `2014-07-06 11:03:12` format
```

Comment: Try this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595754/round-down-datetime-to-previous-hour

Comment: or `strptime(..).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')`

Comment: Wondercricket's suggestion work, I will type it as the answer for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strptime(..).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')`

Adding this to the line as commented by Wondercricket gave me the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Note: this returns a `string`

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

print(datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0,second=0,minute=0)-timedelta(hours=1))
```

Comment: Note: this returns a `datetime` object