# Python Round DOWN time to 5 minutes

Tags: python, datetime, time, rounding

I need to write a function that can ROUND DOWN time to 5 minutes. I mean if it's 17:01 it goes to 17:00, if it's 16:59 it goes to 16:55, if it's 16:51 it goes to 16:50, etc.

Comment: What type of variable is the time stored in?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your code as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round down datetime to previous hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595754/round-down-datetime-to-previous-hour)

Answer (score 2):

The question I linked in the comments, applied to your question could look like

```
from datetime import datetime

l = [datetime.strptime('16:59', "%H:%M").time(), datetime.strptime('17:01', "%H:%M").time()]
# [datetime.time(16, 59), datetime.time(17, 1)]

l_rounded = [d.replace(minute=d.minute-d.minute%5) for d in l]
# [datetime.time(16, 55), datetime.time(17, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you store your time as a string, i.e `hh:mm`, the problem becomes very simple.
We only need to change the last character.
Implementation:

```
def convertStr(s):
  x = s[-1]
  if(int(x)<5):
     return s[:-1] + '0'
  else:
     return s[:-1] + '5'
```

Note that we always need 2 characters in hh and mm for this to work

Answer (score 0):

If having a `datetime.datetime` object, this can be often be done using [`pandas.Timestamp.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html).

```
> import datetime
> import pandas as pd

> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
> dt
datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 6, 12, 43, 17, 640963)

> dt_floored = pd.Timestamp(dt).floor('5T').to_pydatetime()
> dt_floored
datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 6, 12, 40)
```

I noticed that this doesn't work for some timezones, e.g. `America/New_York`.