# How to round down a datetime to the nearest 5 Minutes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, rounding

I need a Python3 function that rounds down a `datetime.datetime` object to the nearest 5 minutes.  Yes, this has been discussed in previous SO posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723150/rounding-up-to-nearest-30-minutes-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595754/round-down-datetime-to-previous-hour) and even [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754405/how-can-i-extract-hours-and-minutes-from-a-datetime-datetime-object), but I'm having no luck implementing their solutions.

**NOTE:  I can not use pandas**

I want a function, given the below DateTime (`%Y%m%d%H%M`) objects, returns the following:

```
INPUT         OUTPUT
202301131600  202301131600
202301131602  202301131600
202301131604  202301131600
202301131605  202301131605
202301131609  202301131605
202301131610  202301131610
```

Here's my code, using [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) as a mechanism:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def roundDownDateTime(dt):
    # Arguments:
    #   dt      DateTime object
    delta = timedelta(minutes=5)
    return dt - (datetime.min - dt) % delta

tmpDate = datetime.now()
# Print the current time and then rounded-down time:
print("\t"+tmpDate.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')+"  -->  "+(roundDownDateTime(tmpDate)).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') )
```

Here's some output when I test the code multiple times:

```
202301131652  -->  202301131650
202301131700  -->  202301131655
202301131701  -->  202301131657
```

Ugh, no good!  I adapted my function to this:

```
def roundDownDateTime(dt):
    # Arguments:
    #   dt      DateTime object
    n = dt - timedelta(minutes=5)
    return datetime(year=n.year, month=n.month, day=n.day, hour=n.hour)
```

But that was even **worse**:

```
202301131703  -->  202301131600
202301131707  -->  202301131700
202301131710  -->  202301131700
```

I am all thumbs when figuring out this basic `datetime` arithmetic stuff; can anyone see my error?

Comment: I don't know what `% timedelta` is supposed to do, but obviously it's the wrong approach for you. I'd try working with the minutes directly.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks Mark, I've edited my OP to include why I tried `timedelta`.  Working with the minutes directly seemed messy and I was kinda hoping there was a simpler way.  Thanks for your advice!

Comment: see also [Python Round DOWN time to 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64845392/10197418)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can only affect the minutes by rounding down to the nearest 5 minutes, just figure out how many minutes you need to subtract. Set everything else from the original datetime object, and seconds and microseconds to zero:

```
def roundDownDateTime(dt):
    delta_min = dt.minute % 5
    return datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day,
                             dt.hour, dt.minute - delta_min)
```

To test:

```
import datetime

expio = [['202301131600', '202301131600'],
 ['202301131602', '202301131600'],
 ['202301131604', '202301131600'],
 ['202301131605', '202301131605'],
 ['202301131609', '202301131605'],
 ['202301131610', '202301131610']]

for i, eo in expio:
    o = roundDownDateTime(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y%m%d%H%M")).strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
    assert eo == o
```

asserts all True

Comment: To be complete you should also set `second` and `microsecond` to zero. It's easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

You have `(datetime.min - dt)` backwards - this results in a negative value which doesn't behave the way you expect with `%`. If you swap to  `(dt - datetime.min)` you get your expected results:

```
In []:
def roundDownDateTime(dt, delta=timedelta(minutes=5)):
    return dt - (dt - datetime.min) % delta

tmpDate = datetime.now()
tmpDate

Out[]:
datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 13, 11, 36, 7, 821196)

In []:
roundDownDateTime(tmpDate)

Out[]:
datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 13, 11, 35)

In []:
roundDownDateTime(tmpDate, timedelta(minutes=10)

Out[]:
datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 13, 11, 30)
```

Comment: As explanation: A negative `timedelta` was correct for the `ceil` case that OP linked because they want to figure out how much to _add_, i.e. they want `delta - ((dt - datetime.min) % delta)`, which is equal to `(datetime.min - dt) % delta`. To figure out how much time we need to _subtract_ for a floor, the `delta - ` part of that expression needs to be removed

Answer (score 1):

I think I would be inclined to obtain the timestamp and round it then convert back to datetime:

```py
def round_datetime(dt, secs):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(secs * (dt.timestamp() // secs))
```

You might test with:

```
import datetime
import time

def round_datetime(dt, secs):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(secs * (dt.timestamp() // secs))

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(now, round_datetime(now, 5 * 60))
    time.sleep(1)
```