# Why aren't identical datetimes equal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, equality

I'm working on a simple Python3 script that considers data in five-minute increments.  [Thanks to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75112399/how-to-round-down-a-datetime-to-the-nearest-5-minutes), I have code which takes any Python datetime object and then rounds it down to the nearest five minutes.  (:00, :05, :10, :15, etc.)  Note that I cannot use pandas.

Now I need to be able to compare that "rounded-down" datetime with other datetimes, and here I'm running into a problem.  Consider this test code:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def roundDownDateTime(dt):
    # Arguments:
    #   dt      datetime object
    delta = timedelta(minutes=1) * (dt.minute % 5)
    return dt - delta

def testAlarm(testDate):
    # Arguments:
    #   testDate    datetime object
    currDate = roundDownDateTime( datetime.now() )      # currDate is a DateTime object, rounded down to 5 mins
    print("currDate:  "+currDate.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M"))
    print("testDate:  "+testDate.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M"))
    if(currDate == testDate):
        print("ALARM!!!!")

def main():
    testDate = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], "%Y%m%d%H%M")
    testAlarm(testDate)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code does all of the following:

- The `main()` function takes a string you enter on the command line,
  then converts it into a `"%Y%m%d%H%M"` datetime
- Your datetime is rounded down to the last five minute increment
- In `testAlarm()`, your date is compared with the current date, also in
  `"%Y%m%d%H%M"` format, also rounded down five minutes.
- If the current date matches the cmd line argument, you should get an
  `"ALARM!!!` in the output.

Here's the actual output, run on my Ubuntu machine:

```
me@unbuntu1$ date
Tue Jan 17 14:27:41 UTC 2023
me@unbuntu1$ 
me@unbuntu1$ python3 toy04.py 202301171425
currDate:  202301171425
testDate:  202301171425
me@unbuntu1$
```

Okay:  Although I'm rounding down my date to match the "rounded-down" version of the current date, the `if(currDate == testDate):` line of code is still evaluating to `False`.  While both datetimes ***appear*** equal in the `"%Y%m%d%H%M"` format, they are somehow not equal.

My first thought was that maybe the "rounded down" datetime still retained some residual seconds or microseconds even after the rounding part?  So I modified my function to this:

```
def roundDownDateTime(dt):
    # Arguments:
    #   dt      DateTime object
    delta = timedelta(minutes=1) * (dt.minute % 5)
    dt = dt - delta
    dt.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
    return dt
```

But that makes no difference; I still get the exact same output as before.

Normally, you would only care if `currDate > testDate` for alarming purposes.  But in my case, I must be able to compare datetimes for equality after one (or more) of them has been through the `roundDownDateTime()` function.  What am I missing?  Is my `roundDownDateTime()` function faulty?  Thank you.

Comment: Most likely this is a floating point rounding error

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects - check if one of them isn't naive. According to docs, "For equality comparisons, naive instances are never equal to aware instances."

Comment: You are printing the `strftime` but comparing the datetime object for `currDate`, which are not equal because of the decimals.

Comment: @It_is_Chris That's a great point, probably the source of my confusion.  What's the recommended way to print datetime's, I wonder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dt.replace` returns a *new* `datetime` object; it does not modify `dt` in place.

```
def roundDownDateTime(dt):
    # Arguments:
    #   dt      DateTime object
    delta = timedelta(minutes=1) * (dt.minute % 5)
    dt = dt - delta
    return dt.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
```